# How to send tabulated dataframe to text area of webpage using selenium python send_keys?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, selenium

So i'm able to print the tabulated dataframe in my console and now i want to send the same tabulated dataframe in an text area of webpage. Below is my code where excel_data_df1 read the excel file as pandas, and i'm using python 3.8. Attached the screenshots for reference.

```
SelectUp = excel_data_df1[(excel_data_df1['Marketplace'] == 'US') & (excel_data_df1['Product Line'] == 'Books')]
Guideline = print(tabulate(SelectUp, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql',showindex=False))
driver.find_element_by_id('tab_work_log').click()
WL = driver.find_element_by_id('work_log')
WL.send_keys(Guideline)
```

[Tabulated dataframe in console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j2T9.jpg)
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLTIh.jpg)

Comment: this looks right. what isn't working? what result are you getting? Consider posting a larger chunk of the source code.

Comment: have given the screenshots also. This is part of the source code which are required.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `print()` method doesn't return actual value i.e. it returns nothing.
This actually causes `Guideline` to become `None` type object.
That's why

```
WL.send_keys(Guideline)
```

actually

```
WL.send_keys(None)
```

throws that error

Comment: So how to send that dataframe?

Comment: You can't send a dataframe to webelement. You can send a string only.